Diff RHEL, Debian, Kernel.org
I have read that RedHat and Debian patch the Kernel.org kernel, apparently they make different changes, which is easy enough to believe, however, I wish to see the difference. Meaning - I basically want to diff it out and get an understanding about exactly what is so different:
RedHat (RHEL) vs Linux.org
Debian vs Linux.org
RedHat (RHEL) vs Debian
In theory, since RHEL is opensource, I should be able to download RHEL kernel source from some git repo. Call me stupid, but so far I can only find CentOS and Fedora (which should be relatively close to RHEL, but I want RHEL).
CentOS: https://git.centos.org/rpms/kernel.git
I did find the Debian kernel: https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux.git
Obviously found the Kernel.Org source: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
Next question (assuming I find the RHEL kernel source) is - if RHEL and Debian are patching the Kernel.Org kernel, how would I sync them all together? Obviously if Linux, Debian and RHEL kernels are all on different Kernel.Org versions, the comparison would be somewhat wrecked.
And last, but not least important (maybe even the better way of doing this) - if it is true, that Debian and RHEL are just patching the upstream Kernel.org... shouldn't I be able to just find repos for Debian and RHEL with just the patches? Then I would be able to just read through the patches and diff the patches against one another to get the information I'm looking for...
UPDATE: It also occurred to me, that I should probably pay attention to the kernel configs

"shouldn't I be able to just find repos for Debian and RHEL with just the patches? " ... Like https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/tree/master/debian/patches?ref_type=heads?

"since RHEL is opensource, I should be able to download RHEL kernel source from some git repo" ... Technically (to an approximation), the terms are usually that if you are given the binary, there should be a way to get the source code as well. There is no requirement that the source code be in a git repo, or that it be online and open to the world. If you can get RHEL, you can get SRPMs for any open source package in RHEL.

RHEL's preferred means of releasing their modifications to the world is via the CentOS repos, which you have already found.

@muru
Tyvm for the link to Debian patches!
So I cloned https://git.centos.org/rpms/kernel/tree and Debian (working on RHEL)  From what I can tell, CentOS has some mention of binary patches in some of their commits - is this how RHEL tries to obfuscate their patches?
